# Get cdc tables in visual studio 2012/2010 database project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, database-project, cdc, change-data-capture

I am trying to create a database project in Visual Studio 2012/2010 where I need the CDC ([Change Data Capture](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522489.aspx)) tables , because lot of my views are dependent on the CDC tables. I couldn't find any way to import the cdc schema/tables :(. Read in many blogs that importing cdc is not supported. Is there any work around. Please suggest

Comment: Workaround that comes to mind is to drop/recreate in a post-deploy script and apply permissions there as well. I've had to do that before when a view depended on objects that were not present or not present yet. They would still be versioned, but not as part of the project.

Answer (score 0):

Generally you wouldn't really want the CDC tables to be created by a database project, you want them to be created using [sys.sp_cdc_enable_table](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522475.aspx)
If you allow the database project to create the tables in a normal manner then the CDC tables would end up existing but their Change Data Capture wouldn't actually be enabled.

Obviously you can script the calls to sys.sp_cdc_enable_table in either Pre or Post scripts, but as far as I can tell neither place is ideal.

If you put the sys.sp_cdc_enable_table calls in a Pre script changes are that not all the original tables exist (on a fresh deploy none of them will exist), or that these original tables will change shape as part of the main deploy that occurs after Pre is run.

If you put the sys.sp_cdc_enable_table calls in the Post script, you can't have Views that rely on the CDC tables existing deployed as part of the main database project deployment (not without errors or warnings in your DB project).

I would suggest not having too many views, functions or stored procs that rely on the existence of the CDC tables, but it sounds like it might be too late for that.
Side Note: Generally speaking you should be using the  [cdc.fn_cdc_get_all_changes_](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510627.aspx) and [cdc.fn_cdc_get_net_changes_](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522511.aspx) functions rather than referencing the cdc tables directly, see [Querying Change Data Capture data](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/44856/querying-change-data-capture-data)
However, that just moves the problem along one level to those functions not existing in your project.
Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be a good way to have those extra views without scripting them at the same point that you script your calls to sys.sp_cdc_enable_table

(I'm honestly hoping someone else will come along with a better answer that actually solves the problem)

Answer (score 0):

We came across the same issue recently in a DB project using TFS/VS for builds during the implementation stage.

As Scott correctly said, it's not a good idea to attempt to implement either cdc schema or any objects inside the project/solution, this has unfortunate consequences which you really do not want to experience!

For TFS/VS projects, you should implement a Pre-PostDeployment Script strategy, whereby CDC can be disabled during the PreDeploy process and then the instances are recreated during the PostDepolyment process.

In this way you can assured that the correct CDC instances are created uniformly.

When you consider the dependent views, again, the strategy is not difficult.
Create the view as you normally would in the project, but as a placeholder (e.g. a simple CREATE dbo.vMyView AS SELECT 1 FROM SomeTable). In the PostDeployment scripts, add a further script that executes **AFTER** the CDC instances have been created, with ALTER statements for those views (e.g. ALTER VIEW dbo.vMyView SELECT Col1 FROM cdc.MyCDC_CT). Remember, a view, once created, can exists even if the underlying table doesn't.